# What does "in full" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a definition of the word "broadside" from TFD

> *verb*
> To strike or collide **with full** on the side: lost control of the truck and broadsided the car.

What does **with full** mean here?

> "full" noun {source TFD}
> 2. The highest degree or state: living life to the full.

Does it mean that "**with full**" is "with the highest degree of power or speed"?

Comment: I  think _with_ belongs with _collide_ and _full_ with _on the side_! I'm not familiar with _broadside_ as a verb, but to hit something _broadside on_ means to strike it at right angles.

Comment: I think to 'broadside' is US casual 'to hit another vehicle sideways-on in a collision' Different from e.g. 'rear-ending' .

Comment: I don't know what TFD is, but I've only heard the idiom as "living life to the fullest"

Comment: I am pretty sure that the TFD is The Free Dictionary.

Comment: He broadsided my car. He collided **with** my car **full on** the side, i.e. not at the front, or rear, or at an angle.

Comment: Yeah, you're just parsing it slightly wrong.  It's (collide with) (full on).

Answer (score 1):

There are several tricky usages here. We usually see *full* as an adjective. You found a less common usage in which it's a noun. However, it's being used here as an adverb. It's usage 2 in [this Merriam-Webster entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/full):

> **full** *adverb*
> 1a: VERY, EXTREMELY
> *// knew full well they had lied to me*
> b: ENTIRELY
> *// swung full around*
> 2: STRAIGHT, SQUARELY
> *// got hit full in the face*

It's more similar in meaning to *fully*, and this construction is almost always used by following it with a preposition ("full on the side," "full in the face").

As Kate observed, the phrases should be understood as: "[collide with] [full on the side]."

Meanwhile, don't confuse it with the phrasal adjective *[full-on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/full-on)*.

Answer (score 0):

*with* relates to *collide* and *full* is a noun meaning [the greatest degree, extent](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/full).

> [To strike] or [(to) collide with] *(how?)* [[full] on the side].